# Web Scraping using bs4 with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with the HTML text I am trying to work with.

I would like to extract the name of the player with all the statistics associated with him.

Basically I am not sure if I can extract the numbers of the column due to the syntax of the code.

In the HTML I included only 2 players, but I would like to add all the players of this club and then continue to the next team.

```html
<table data-toggle="table-estadisticas-clubes" data-fixed-columns="true" data-fixed-number="2" class="roboto">
    <thead>
        <tr class="cabecera_general">
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>PAR</th>
            <th>MIN</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>PT</th>
            <th colspan="3">TIROS DE 3</th>
            <th colspan="3">TIROS DE 2</th>
            <th colspan="3">TIROS LIBRES</th>
            <th colspan="3">REBOTES</th>
            <th>ASI</th>
            <th colspan="2">BALONES</th>
            <th colspan="2">TAPONES</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th colspan="2">FALTAS</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="ultimo">VAL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="situacion">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="nombre jugador">&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Jug</th>
            <th>Jug</th>
            <th>5i</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Con</th>
            <th>Int</th>
            <th>%</th>
            <th>Con</th>
            <th>Int</th>
            <th>%</th>
            <th>Con</th>
            <th>Int</th>
            <th>%</th>
            <th>Def</th>
            <th>Ofe</th>
            <th>Tot</th>
            <th>Efe</th>
            <th>Rec</th>
            <th>Per</th>
            <th>Fav</th>
            <th>Con</th>
            <th>Mat</th>
            <th>Com</th>
            <th>Rec</th>
            <th>+/-</th>
            <th class="ultimo">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="situacion"></td>
            <td class="nombre jugador ellipsis"><a href="/jugador/ver/30000024-William-Magarity"><span class="nombre_corto">William Magarity</span></a></td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">2</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">23:57</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho"></td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">11,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">3,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">4,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">75,0%</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">2,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">20,0%</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">1,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">1,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">100,0%</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">3,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">3,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">1,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">1,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">1,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">2,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">1,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">16,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="par">
            <td class="situacion"></td>
            <td class="nombre jugador ellipsis"><a href="/jugador/ver/30000283-Jaime-Echenique"><span class="nombre_corto">Jaime Echenique</span></a></td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">2</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">23:34</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho"></td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">14,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">1,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">50,0%</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">3,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">7,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">50,0%</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">5,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">6,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">91,7%</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">3,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">3,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">1,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">2,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">2,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">0,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">3,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">4,0</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">-1,5</td>
            <td class="borde_derecho">15,5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

URL: https://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/14

Comment: can you show us code that you've already tried, the problems you're running into?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to parse the table is to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.acb.com/club/estadisticas/id/14'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0].iloc[:,1:]
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Will grab the table to dataframe and saves it as `data.csv`:

[image]

Comment: That's perfect @Andrej!

Thank you very much for your help.